# What- Phrase in a cleft sentence

Tags: bare-infinitives, cleft-constructions

I was reading about how lengthy wording is moved to end the Clause by placing everything in a **what-phrase** at the beginning of the clause. And, I found this example-

What he did was **exceed** our expectations and **push** performance art to a new level.

I can't understand why there is a plain form of verb used instead of past form. Was/were usually takes third or fourth form of verb or sometimes Infinitives too. But never bare infinitives or plain form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What he did was* [*exceed our expectations*] and [*push performance art to a*
> *new level*].

"What he did" is a noun phrase in a 'fused' relative construction. The fusion involves "what", which can be glossed as "that which" (or "the thing which").

In constructions where the subject noun phrase contains "do" in a relative clause, as it does here, the complement of "be" is restricted to infinitival clauses, either bare or with "to" added.

"Exceed our expectations" and "push performance art to a new level" form a coordination of two clauses, and since the first coordinate is an infinitival the second coordinate should also be one. Infinitival clauses contain a plain form of the verb, hence "exceed" and "push".

Answer (score 1):

We can analyze this sentence's structure as SVC (subject-verb-complement):

> Subject: what he did
> Verb: was
> Complement: **exceed** our expectations and **push** performance art to a new level

The subject is a nominal clause. It is fairly straightforward, with the wh-word (which functions as the clause's direct object) fronted.

The complement (in this case a predicate nominative) is a series containing two conjunts connected by "and". Each conjunct is a nominal phrase headed by a bare infinitive (which I've put in bold). It is, indeed, somewhat unusual for a bare infinitive to head a nominal phrase, but it is correct. BillJ notes that this is possible because the nominal clause's main verb is "to do".

Here is an example of a similar construction from what I believe is a transcript of a House of Lords committee hearing (["House of Lords - Committee for Privileges and Conduct: The Conduct of Lord Laird - HL 96: 10th Report of Session 2013-14", pg. 211](https://www.google.com/books/edition/House_of_Lords_Committee_for_Privileges/0_BoNy0bBPEC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22what%20you%20do%20is%20go%22&pg=PA211)):

> Subject: what you do
> Verb: is
> Complement: **go** outside and **try** to create the climate of opinion

By the way, this is sometimes called a "pseudo-cleft sentence". It is not the most typical kind of cleft sentence.

Comment: @ MarclnManhattan I just read in Michael Swan book that when we have to  Emphasise verbs in these types of sentences, Infinitives with 'to' and without 'to' are possible. Ex- what he did was (to) scream.  But why he bracketed 'to' ? And in various other sources I found they much prefer Bare infinitive to full Infinitive.

Comment: @RADS He bracketed "to" because it is optional. That sentence is correct whether "scream" is a bare or full infinitive.

Comment: It would be helpful to give the reason the complement consists of infinitival clauses. The crucial fact is that when the the subject noun phrase contains "do" in a relative clause, as it does here, the complement of "be" is restricted to infinitival clauses. Elsewhere there is no such restriction, cf. _The funniest thing was Kim trying to hide in the coal-box_.

Comment: @BillJ Done, thanks.